# Direct clipboard manipulation with Selenium WebDriver

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver

Is it possible to use Selenium WebDriver to pre-populate the clipboard with some text to be pasted, as though the text had been copied in another application? (Ideally using the Python bindings?)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

No, it seems not – as a **browser** manipulation tool, Selenium is designed to perform functions unique to browsers. In general, clipboard manipulation is a function handled by a **file manager**, usually one which includes a GUI, such as Windows Explorer or the Mac OS Finder.

There *are* ways for the various Selenium interfaces (Java, Python, etc) to access clipboard functions, but these only work if the browser in question is running in a context which contains them. If Selenium is running headless (meaning with no GUI, e.g. using a virtual display such as [Xvfb](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Xvfb), possibly as part of a virtual machine) there may not be any accessible context with clipboard functionality, and Selenium itself does not provide any on its own.

Answer (score 2):

A hack you can do to "pre-populate" the clipboard is to perform the steps a user would take to copy it into the clipboard.

one way to do this (assuming you have some text you want to copy), is to open a url containing the text, press the keys 'ctrl-a' while the body has the focus, then press the keys 'ctrl-c'

```
driver.findElements(By.tagname("body")).type(Keys.chord(keys.control, 'a'));
driver.findElements(By.tagname("body")).type(Keys.chord(keys.control, 'c'));
```

you might have to put a sleep between each step, so that the OS has time to actually perform the copy operation - i find that sometimes, selenium runs too fast.