# Testing paste functionality of a HTML5 application using selenium grid

Tags: selenium, selenium-grid

I have some tests which I am able to run on my local PC using webdriver which make use of [`java.awt.datatransfer.Clipboard`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/awt/datatransfer/Clipboard.html) to set contents and paste into a HTML5 application.  How can I accomplish something similar when using Selenium grid where the tests are executed remotely?

Is it possible for instance to type into the address bar but not actually visit that page, select that text and then send keys for <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>C</kbd> to get the text into the remote clipboard?

[This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16175137/383838) suggests that it's not possible although given that was written over 6 years ago things may have changed, especially given the current prevalence of rich HTML5 applications on the desktop.  Does selenium not support this facet of user interface testing?

Comment: I'm quite surprised by your comment, I wouldn't be asking this question if I had managed to find anything at all about the functionality of webdriver and the clipboard online, all the top results on Google refer to running webdriver on the same machine as the test code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how we do copying and pasting locally (Example in C#):

```
            Thread thread = new Thread(() => Clipboard.SetText(text));
            thread.SetApartmentState(ApartmentState.STA);
            thread.Start();
            thread.Join();
            element.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control + "v");
```

Here is how we do copying and pasting on a grid node:

```
        string toPaste = "something";
        element.SendKeys(toPaste);
        element.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control + "a"); //select all
        element.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control + "c"); //copy 
        elementTwo.SendKeys(OpenQA.Selenium.Keys.Control + "v"); //paste
```

You have to have somewhere to type the text into before selecting it (highlighting it) and then copying and pasting.  This is the way that it will work on a node.  If you couldn't use a textbox in your own application you could always go to google.com and type in the search bar.  Then copy that text as the first step of your test, navigate to your application and paste it in.

But if you have two tests running on the same machine(grid node) at the same time, the clipboard resource is not going to be thread safe.  You might need to implement some custom locking logic

Comment: Does `Clipboard.SetText` propagate onto a Selenium Grid node?

Comment: I added some more information to my answer.  I don't think Clipboard.SetText is going to work how you want it to.  You have to type the text out somewhere on the node so you can copy it onto your clipboard. The 2nd example we use on grid nodes and it works