# Print element copied with the send_keys (Keys.CONTROL, "v")

Tags: python, selenium, copy

How do I display a text that I copied with the function send_keys (Keys.CONTROL, "v")  to display it with the print command?

Comment: Do you have to "cut" the text for your test? Or can you simply locate the text (which you must've done in order to find the text to cut)

Comment: no, the text has been copied in full by clicking a hypertext button. I would also like to be able to display it at the end with the "print" function

Comment: Does the page with the "copy link" button also display the link? If so, just get the text in the div/field which displays the link.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to get an input and save it to a variable.
Like this:

```
your_text = driver.find_element_by_id("my_id").get_attribute("value")
print(your_text)
```

Comment: Thank you! I was able to store it in that variable. Resolved

Comment: Happy it helped)

Answer (score 0):

No, you can't do this with selenium alone. Selenium is a browser control and the clipboard is a system level process. You would need to involve other software to properly manipulate the clipboard.

See alos [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16175137/1387701) for confirmation of the above statements.

Comment: What if I paste that item into a search box? Then after extrapolating the text pasted with find. element (value)?
I noticed that the value of the search box returns the text I am looking for.
After I paste it becomes for example ------ value = "item copied"
I hope I was clear

Comment: yes you could do that. By sending ctrl+v keys

Comment: yes, however, that pasted text, I would also like to view it on the terminal with the print command, or paste it in a csv file

Comment: If you're using that method, then once you've pasted it into the search box, get elem.text for that box and now you've got the value in a variable. You can then write it to CSV or print it as required, as you normally would; you don't need to "paste" it into a csv.